# Xtext 2.8+ formatter, formatting HiddenRegion with comment

Tags: eclipse, formatting, xtext, xtend

I am using Xtext 2.9 formatter and I am trying to **format hiddenRegion** which contains **comment**. Here is part of my document region i am trying to format:

```
Columns: 1:offset 2:length 3:kind 4: text 5:grammarElement
Kind: H=IHiddenRegion S=ISemanticRegion B/E=IEObjectRegion

35  0 H
35 15 S ""xxx::a::b""        Refblock:namespace=Namespace
50  0 H
50  1 S "}"                  Refblock:RCBRACKET
      E Refblock             PackageHead:Block=Refblock path:PackageHead/Block=Package'xxx_constants'/head=Model/packages[0]
51  0 H
51  1 S ":"                  PackageHead:COLON
      E PackageHead          Package:head=PackageHead path:Package'xxx_constants'/head=Model/packages[0]
52    >>>H "\n    "             Whitespace:TerminalRule'WS'
        "# asd"              Comment:TerminalRule'SL_COMMENT'
   15   "\n    "             Whitespace:TerminalRule'WS'<<<
      B Error'ASSD'          Package:expressions+=Expression path:Package'xxx_constants'/expressions[0]=Model/packages[0]
67  5 S "error"              Error:'error'
72  1 H " "                  Whitespace:TerminalRule'WS'
```

and corresponding part of the grammar

```
Model:
    {Model}
    (packages+=Package)*;

Expression:
    Error | Warning | Enum | Text;

Package:
    {Package}
    'package' name=Name head=PackageHead
    (BEGIN
    (imports+=Import)*
    (expressions+=Expression)*
    END)?;

Error:
    {Error}
    ('error') name=ENAME parameter=Parameter COLON
    (BEGIN
    (expressions+=Estatement)+
    END)?;

PackageHead:
    Block=Refblock COLON;
```

Problem is that when i try prepend some characters before error keyword
for example

```
error.regionFor.keyword('error').prepend[setSpace("\n    ")]
```

This indentation is **prepended before the comment and not behind it**. This results into improper formatting in case of single line comment before the 'error' keyword.

To provide more clarity, here is example code from my grammar and description of desired behavior:

```
package xxx_constants {namespace="xxx::a::b"}:
     # asd
     error ASSD {0}:
         Hello {0,world}
```

This is **expected result**: (one space to the left)

```
package xxx_constants {namespace="xxx::a::b"}:
    # asd
    error ASSD {0}:
         Hello {0,world}
```

and this is the **actual result** with prepend method

```
package xxx_constants {namespace="xxx::a::b"}:
    # asd
error ASSD {0}:
         Hello {0,world}
```

As the document structure says, the HiddenRegion is in this case is the statement:

```
# asd
    error
```

**How can i prepend my characters directly before the keyword 'error' and not before the comment?** Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're creating an indentation-sensitive language, because you're explicitly calling `BEGIN` and `END`.

For indentation-sensitive language my answer is: You'll want to overwrite

```
org.eclipse.xtext.formatting2.internal.HiddenRegionReplacer.applyHiddenRegionFormatting(List<ITextReplacer>)
```

The methods append[] and prepend[] you're using are agnostic to comments and at a later time applyHiddenRegionFormatting() is called to decide how that formatting is weaved between comments.

To make Xtext use your own subclass of HiddenRegionReplacer, overwrite

```
org.eclipse.xtext.formatting2.AbstractFormatter2.createHiddenRegionReplacer(IHiddenRegion, IHiddenRegionFormatting)
```

For languages that do *not* do whitespace-sensitive lexing/parsing (that's the default) the answer is to *not* call setSpace() to create indentation or line-wraps.

Instead, do

```
pkg.interior[indent]
pkg.regionFor.keyword(":").append[newLine]
pkg.append[newLine]
```

Comment: Thank you, overriding org.eclipse.xtext.formatting2.internal.HiddenRegionReplacer.applyHiddenRegionFormatting(List<ITextReplacer>)
 worked.

Comment: What is this pkg.interior - how do I get that in AbstractJavaFormatter?